# C# How to I create a set of sets

Tags: c#, set

I want to create a set of sets (of int)

something like:

```
SortedSet<SortedSet<int>>
```

or

```
HashSet<HashSet<int>>
```

but when trying to match the sets it uses ReferenceEquals to compare

and thus is useless for my purpose

is there a way to make a set of sets useful in C#?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you have two sets that contain the same int, and seem the same, they will be interpreted as different objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass [`HashSet<int>.CreateSetComparer()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335475) to the outer set to compare by reference.

Comment: could you give an example?

Comment: found it elsewhere - `HashSet<HashSet<int>> setOfSets = new HashSet<HashSet<int>>(HashSet<int>.CreateSetComparer())`